# Django Rest Logout , Integrate Rest under admin

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Project Url is,

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')) )
```

My App Url is

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^snippets/$', views.snippet_list),]
```

While openning the browsable api ( 127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/) it ask the username and password to authenticate but while clicking the logout it was not logged out.

And how to implement /snippets under admin section

like After logged into admin only I can able to access the snippets

( Integrating this API service under django admin)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Django Rest Framework (DRF) [permissions documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/).

You need to figure out what your default permissions model is for your view and then change the global default or override it appropriately for a specific view.

Also, is there a reason you're not using the [DRF router](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) in `urls.py`?